# Redirect To Action Not Working after login ASP.NET Core Identity (.Net 5)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Even after a successful sign-in it does not redirect to action but stays on the login page.

I have put breakpoints but have not been able to know what exactly is wrong with my code.

Even if the condition is true the code is not executed.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == model.UserName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, true, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var role = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                    if (role.Contains("Client"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyDashboard");
                    }

                    if (role.Contains("Admin"))
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
       
        return View();
}
```

Comment: Show us your **full** Controller definition. Have you looked at the raw HTTP requests/responses?

Comment: Only two action methods exist in the Account Controller. The other method returns View.

Comment: Are you sure that your code reaches the RedirectToAction  lines?

Comment: Yes, it reaches there.

Comment: As soon as it reaches there, it comes out of the if block and goes to the end of the method.

Comment: Check if you are trying to redirect to a different Area than the one you are already in. You can also try to use RedirectToPage instead of RedirectToAction.

Comment: No areas in my Application,  and secondly i want to redirect to an action method and not a razor page.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution myself. Actually, I was missing Authentication middleware in the startup class. After adding app.UseAuthentication() ,it works fine. Thanks.